# How to run a command once after a certain time (RoR)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I want to run a command 48 hours after I set some flag. For example the column gets updated and 48 hours later the command gets executed. I know I can use 'whenever' gem and just schedule the hourly (daily, etc.) checks, but what if I just want to run 1 command once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delayed Job and its run_at option works well for this.

[Zada's Notes: Rails Tips: Using delayed_job to schedule jobs at specific times](http://zadasnotes.blogspot.com/2011/03/rails-tips-using-delayedjob-to-schedule.html)